# Alternative to nohup when input user is requested

Tags: java, user-input, nohup, shutdown-hook

I've got a java application which is started with a nohup command.
Now the stop command is just a kill -15 of that application. This application is a file parsing and write to db application and it has a shutdown hooker which intercepts the kill command and then does some releasing resources and cleaning database stuff...

Now, this cleaning process expects some input user (Y or N) for each file to release (basically, for each file that is still being parsed the application asks to wait for its completion or interrupt the process and do some cleaning on db).

The nohup command ignores standard input so the java input reader is ignored. How can I sort it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass this input to user hook using some property file.
In your shutdown hook, you can can read input from a predefined set of properties.

I dont think you can make it dynamic by asking user to enter y or n , also how will user know while file is being parsed? It should be pre defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The user is informed with the list of files under parsing (files are processed by different thread and I have concurrent maps to put and remove files while parsing). One by one the user is asked to choose if to stop parsing of that particular file...

I think you are right that this should be predefined because I don't think there is a way to avoid hanghups and permit some user input in an interactive manner.

Comment: Files come with without any predefined rule, from different channels. Anyway, I think this is quite unrelated with the problem I pose.